# why UserWarning:fuzz needs pycurl to run

Tags: directory, homebrew

i'm trying to find directories with wfuzz but i only get this error

/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wfuzz/_*init*_.py:49: UserWarning:fuzz needs pycurl to run. Pycurl could be installed using the following command: $ pip install pycurl

it suppose to give me some directories but all i get is this error .

i tied this:

https://wfuzz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html#pycurl-on-macos

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.